# What is the best way to change images based on the last 3 characters on the URL?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to change images based on the last 3 characters on the URL?
I have 3 pictures but when click - needs to stay as the selected image, 
but the page refreshes and goes back to original image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function image_swap() {
  var URLChar = $(location).attr('href').charAt($(location).attr('href').length - 3)
  if (URLChar("NSW"); image.src = "../MCFILES/NSW1.jpg"
    if (URLChar("VIC"); image.src = "../MCFILES/VIC1.jpg"
      if (URLChar("QLD"); image.src = "../MCFILES/QLD1.jpg"
      } else {
        image.src = "../MCFILES/NSW1.jpg"
      }
    }

    function newDocNSW() {
      var CurrentURL = window.location.href;
      var OriginalURL = CurrentURL.replace(/\&.*/, '');
      window.location.assign(OriginalURL + "&St=NSW");
    }

    function newDocQLD() {
      var CurrentURL = window.location.href;
      var OriginalURL = CurrentURL.replace(/\&.*/, '');
      window.location.assign(OriginalURL + "&St=QLD");
    }

    function newDocVIC() {
      var CurrentURL = window.location.href;
      var OriginalURL = CurrentURL.replace(/\&.*/, '');
      window.location.assign(OriginalURL + "&St=VIC");
    }
</script>
<body>
```

This is the images i need to change when on hover and when click 
runs another script to change URL.

When the page refreshes i need the option to have change picture
when page refreshes to change the URL

```
<img id="image_swap" src="../MCFILES/NSWO.jpg"
onclick="newDocNSW()"
onmouseover="this.src='../MCFILES/NSW1.jpg';"
onmouseout="this.src='../MCFILES/NSWO.jpg';">

<img id="image_swap" src="../MCFILES/QLDO.jpg"
onclick="newDocQLD()"
onmouseover="this.src='../MCFILES/QLD1.jpg';"
onmouseout="this.src='../MCFILES/QLDO.jpg';">

<img id="image_swap" src="../MCFILES/VICO.jpg"
onclick="newDocVIC()"
onmouseover="this.src='../MCFILES/VIC1.jpg';"
onmouseout="this.src='../MCFILES/VICO.jpg';">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is not really clear. From what I could understand, you want to change the page when the image is clicked. And when the page is changed, the new page should show a different image. Is this is Single Page Application? Are you using HTML5s `history` API?

Comment: I'm using javascript in SharePoint.  Basically it is one page and onclick it refreshes the page with a suffix to the URL.  The images still come up with the old image.  When someone clicks on NSW for example - when the page refreshes it should have the active image (ie.NSW1) image on the page.  When users then click on QLD - the page refreshes and the QLD image (QLD1.jpg) and the rest should be NSWO.jpg and VICO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This line will only extract a single character

```
var URLChar = $(location).attr('href').charAt($(location).attr('href').length - 3 )
```

If you want the last three characters then use this:

```
var URLChar = $(location).attr('href').substring($(location).attr('href').length - 3, $(location).attr('href').length);
```

A much simpler plain/vanilla JavaScript approach would be:

```
var URLChar = location.href.substring(location.href.length - 3, location.href.length);
```

Your if conditions are also syntactically incorrect. Here's how it should be:

```
if (URLChar === "NSW"){
    image.src = "../MCFILES/NSW1.jpg";
} else if (URLChar === "VIC"){
    image.src = "../MCFILES/VIC1.jpg";
} else if (URLChar === "QLD"){
    image.src = "../MCFILES/QLD1.jpg";
} else {
    image.src = "../MCFILES/NSW1.jpg";
}
```

I think this should do if I'm understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: I changed the script - It sort of works - but now when I click the icons - it doesn't run the newDOC??? script.....the page doesn't refresh with the new value so I cannot see if the image would change when page refreshes..... any hints

Comment: I changed the script - It sort of works - but now when I click the icons - it doesn't run the newDOC??? script.....the page doesn't refresh with the new value so I cannot see if the image would change when page refreshes..... any hints –